# Scroll View unavailable on all Iphones, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, user-experience

I am testing my app on the different iPhones, I got a problem with my detail view controller. 
I add a **scroll view** to have all the informations and a big picture:

 ( My UITextView go out of the UIControllerView, It is maybe the problem. Can I increase the seize of my UIViewController?)

[image: Comment]
[image: Scroll view].

On the **IPhone5/5S**, I can scroll but the end of my text is hidden:

[image: IPhone5]

On the **IPhone6/6S**, I can't scroll and the end of my text is hidden too.

**How can I fix it, please??**

Thank you!!

Comment: make sure that `contentSize` is larger then the scroll view size

Comment: Thanks, I tried : `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height:self.view.bounds.size.width + 200)` without success. I guess it is because my UITextview is out the UIViewController..(added a picture)

Comment: you used `width` in the height parameter

Comment: I went too fast with the copy/paste.. I tried again, no change. How can I increase the height of my ViewController?

Comment: as you can see on iphone5, your text is also being cut. your label may be too small or the contentSize is still too small.

Comment: I decrease the height of the white UIView and I moved the UIText a little bit higher, now it is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ContentSize of scroll view is almost same as your view's height. to fix this contentSize of your scroll view should be at least self.view's height + 100.0f.

```
public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var scrolviewheight :CGFloat = CGFloat(750)
    let newHeight = scrolviewheight - self.frame.height
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, self.frame.height + newHeight)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to test it right now. Nevertheless my UItextView is out my UIViewController, I guess it is the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a ViewContainer in my UIViewController. 
I change the UIViewControlloer embed for an UITableViewController.
Just need to implement a PerformForSegue.

[image]

Comment: Basically with only one tableViewController and a custom Section , it is the same. The real advantage with a tableViewController is that you can add a refresh mode. ( Entirely the same thing than Instagram)